Unable to terminate script from executions UI
I'm running into an issue where I am attempting to terminate my script from the executions tab UI, however, when I click on the three dots related to the running unction the terminate option is grayed out.
I noticed the status does not say running when it is appending items to my sheet, it instead says the status is paused. However, it is going through my sheet and adding values.
Here is the script that cannot be terminated from the UI.
function onCheckboxEdits(e) {
  let sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  let ss  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let editResults = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,1).getValue();
  let date = new Date();
  date = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-4", 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  if(sheetName == "TESTING" && editResults == true) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,1).setBackground('red');
    console.log('begin updates')
    try{
      let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert('Updates will start once "OK" is clicked. Click "OK" to begin!');
      clearRange(ss,sheetName);
      insertFormula(ss,sheetName);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,1).setValue(false);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(2,1).setValue('Last Run: '+date);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,1).setBackground('white');
      ui.alert('Updates Complete');
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log('error: '+ e);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,1).setValue(false);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(1,1).setBackground('white');
      
    }
  }
  return;
}


function insertFormula(ss,sheetName){
  Logger.log('begin adding formulas');
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('TESTING');
  let srcRange = sheet.getRange('D2:D');
  let srcValues = srcRange.getValues();
  /**SRC ARR is used to calculate the total amount of rows in column D.
   * get values returns a 2d array, we then convert that to a 1d array, 
   * and loop through the total amount of rows.
  */
  let srcArr = srcValues.map(([str])=>(str));
  for (i in srcArr){
    let currentValue = srcArr[i];
    let equation = formulas(i);
    let destRange1 = sheet.getRange('S'+(Number(i)+2));


    if(currentValue!==''){
      destRange1.setValue(equation.sFormula);
      /**
       * Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance, such as when doing multiple calls to Range.getValue().
       *  However, sometimes you may want to make sure that all pending changes are made right away, for instance to show users data as a script is executing.
       */
      pasteValues(ss,sheetName);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    //If the value returned at index i is empty that means there is no more URLs to go through, so we can stop here.
    else if(currentValue==''){
      console.log('On run '+(Number(i)+2)+" no value was detected in column D, no more formulas can be appended.")
      return;
    }

  }
  Logger.log('Formulas have been inserted, and values have been pasted.')
}
function clearRange(ss, sheetName){
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange('S2:W').clearContent();
}
function pasteValues(ss,sheetName){
  let sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let range = sheet.getRange('S2:W');
  let values = range.getValues();
  sheet.getRange('S2:W').setValues(values);
}


There aren't enough details. Please add a [mcve] including a description of the spreadsheet and how the execution is started. P.D. The code calls function like clearRange and pasteValues but they are not included.

The spreadsheet basically contains a list of urls, the phone numbers on said urls, and then compares the phone numbers on the site to what I expect to be on the site.
I believe the issue is related to the onCheckboxEdits function AND Spreadsheetapp.flush(). The onCheckboxEdits function is triggered by an edit trigger.
What I'm not sure is if that in itself is disabling my ability to terminate the function.

let equation = formulas(i); Formulas is not defined.

FWIW, I have had varying "Status" values on the script. Sometimes the Status is "Running", sometimes "Paused", sometimes "Completed" even though it consistently reports error: ReferenceError: formulas is not defined and does not process past that point in "insertFormula()". When the Executions Tab is closed and then opened at a later date, all Status values = "Completed"

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/78880589/1595451
